# Obtaining decoder MFT for H.264 video

Tags: c++, winapi, video, h.264, ms-media-foundation

i am trying to get a hardware decoder from media foundation. i know for sure my gpu supports nvdec hardware decoding. i found an example on github which gets the encoder, nvenc without any problem. but when i switch the params to decoder, i either get a bad hresult or a crash. i tried even getting a software decoder by changing the hardware flag, and still bad hresult. any one have an idea what is wrong? i cant think of anything else left for me to try or change

```
HRESULT get_decoder(CComPtr<IMFTransform>& out_transform, CComPtr<IMFActivate>& out_activate,
    CComPtr<IMFAttributes>& out_attributes)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Find the decoder
    CComHeapPtr<IMFActivate*> activate_raw;
    uint32_t activateCount = 0;

    // Input & output types
    const MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO in_info = { MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_H264 };
    const MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO out_info = { MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_NV12 };

    // Get decoders matching the specified attributes
    if (FAILED(hr = MFTEnum2(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_DECODER, MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SORTANDFILTER, &in_info, &out_info,
        nullptr, &activate_raw, &activateCount)))
        return hr;

    // Choose the first returned decoder
    out_activate = activate_raw[0];

    // Memory management
    for (int i = 1; i < activateCount; i++)
        activate_raw[i]->Release();

    // Activate
    if (FAILED(hr = out_activate->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&out_transform))))
        return hr;

    // Get attributes
    if (FAILED(hr = out_transform->GetAttributes(&out_attributes)))
        return hr;

    std::cout << "- get_decoder() Found " << activateCount << " decoders" << std::endl;

    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be no dedicated decoder MFT for hardware decoding (even though some vendors supply those). Hardware video decoding, in contrast to encoding, is available via DXVA 2 API, and - in turn - is covered by [Microsoft H264 Video Decoder MFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-decoder).

This stock MFT is capable to decode using hardware and is also compatible with D3D9 and D3D11 enabled pipelines.

> ### Microsoft H264 Video Decoder MFT
>
> 6 Attributes:
>
> - MFT_TRANSFORM_CLSID_Attribute: {62CE7E72-4C71-4D20-B15D-452831A87D9D} (Type VT_CLSID, CLSID_CMSH264DecoderMFT)
> - MF_TRANSFORM_FLAGS_Attribute: MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT
> - MFT_INPUT_TYPES_Attributes: MFVideoFormat_H264, MFVideoFormat_H264_ES
> - MFT_OUTPUT_TYPES_Attributes: MFVideoFormat_NV12, MFVideoFormat_YV12, MFVideoFormat_IYUV, MFVideoFormat_I420, MFVideoFormat_YUY2
>
> ##### Attributes
>
> - MF_SA_D3D_AWARE: 1 (Type VT_UI4)
> - MF_SA_D3D11_AWARE: 1 (Type VT_UI4)
> - CODECAPI_AVDecVideoThumbnailGenerationMode: 0 (Type VT_UI4)
> - CODECAPI_AVDecVideoMaxCodedWidth: 7680 (Type VT_UI4)
> - CODECAPI_AVDecVideoMaxCodedHeight: 4320 (Type VT_UI4)
> - CODECAPI_AVDecNumWorkerThreads: 4294967295 (Type VT_UI4, -1)
> - CODECAPI_AVDecVideoAcceleration_H264: 1 (Type VT_UI4)
>   ...

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-decoder#transform-attributes):

> `CODECAPI_AVDecVideoAcceleration_H264`    Enables or disables hardware acceleration.
>
> ...
>
> Maximum Resolution    4096 × 2304 pixels
> The maximum guaranteed resolution for DXVA acceleration is 1920 × 1088 pixels; at higher resolutions, decoding is done with DXVA, if it is supported by the underlying hardware, otherwise, decoding is done with software.
>
> ...
>
> DXVA  The decoder supports DXVA version 2, but not DXVA version 1. DXVA decoding is supported only for Main-compatible Baseline, Main, and High profile bitstreams. (Main-compatible Baseline bitstreams are defined as profile_idc=66 and constrained_set1_flag=1.)

To decode with hardware acceleration just use Microsoft H264 Video Decoder MFT.

Comment: Was able to get the decoder, just had to disable the remove the pAttributes argument. Thank you. I edited my original post to include the correct code now

Comment: Just to clarify - this MFT is NOT async, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is `MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT`